# How to implement custom segue animations?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I subclassed `UIStoryboardSegue` to perform custom segue animations. To make the animation visible I have to add the view from the destination `ViewController` as a temp view. After performing the animations I am removing the temp view and presenting the final `ViewController` via (**presentViewController:animated:NO**).

This however leads to the following warning: *"Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for"*.

If I keep my temp-view and do not remove it the warning does not appear but the final view does not respond to touch events anymore. How to get rid of this warning?

My custom segue code:

```
-(void)perform {

    UIViewController *sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController;

    destinationViewController.view.alpha = 0.;
    destinationViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(destinationViewController.view.transform, 4.0, 4.0);

    [sourceViewController.view addSubview:destinationViewController.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:kSSSpriteKitFadeOutDuration
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{

                         destinationViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(destinationViewController.view.transform, 0.25, 0.25);
                         destinationViewController.view.alpha = 1.;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [destinationViewController.view removeFromSuperview]; // remove from temp super view
                         [sourceViewController presentViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO completion:NULL]; // present VC
                     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am taking 4 `UIStoryboardSegue` type class. 2 for animation start and rest 2 for animation stop. So i am going to share all code for 4 classes. please try to solve this.

**CustomSegue.h**

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 @interface CustomSegue : UIStoryboardSegue

 // Originating point for animation
 @property CGPoint originatingPoint;
 @property CGRect Startingframe;
 @end
```

**CustomSegue.m**

```
 #import "CustomSegue.h"
 @implementation CustomSegue

 - (void)perform
 {
   UIViewController *sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController;
   UIViewController *destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController;

   // Add the destination view as a subview, temporarily
   [sourceViewController.view addSubview:destinationViewController.view];

   // Transformation start scale
   float width = 320;
   float height = 480;

   float x_Scale = self.Startingframe.size.width/width;
   float Y_Scale = self.Startingframe.size.height/height;

   destinationViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(x_Scale, Y_Scale);

   // Store original centre point of the destination view
   CGPoint originalCenter = destinationViewController.view.center;
   // Set center to start point of the button
   destinationViewController.view.center = self.originatingPoint;

   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^
                {
                     // Grow!
                      destinationViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);

                     destinationViewController.view.center = originalCenter;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
                {
                     [destinationViewController.view removeFromSuperview]; // remove from temp super view
                     [sourceViewController presentViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO completion:NULL]; // present VC
                 }];
 }

 @end
```

**CustomUnwindSegue.h**

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 @interface CustomUnwindSegue : UIStoryboardSegue

 // Target point to animate to (on the button)
 @property CGPoint targetPoint;
 @property CGRect endFrame;

 @end
```

**CustomUnwindSegue.m**

```
 #import "CustomUnwindSegue.h"

 @implementation CustomUnwindSegue

 - (void)perform {
    UIViewController *sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController;

    // Transformation End scale
    float width = 320;
    float height = 480;

    float x_Scale = self.endFrame.size.width/width;
    float Y_Scale = self.endFrame.size.height/height;
    // Add view to super view temporarily
    [sourceViewController.view.superview insertSubview:destinationViewController.view atIndex:0];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     // Shrink!
                     sourceViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(x_Scale, Y_Scale);
                     sourceViewController.view.center = self.targetPoint;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [destinationViewController.view removeFromSuperview]; // remove from temp super view
                     [sourceViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL]; // dismiss VC
                 }];
}

@end
```

Just connect your action with this custom segue animation like below:

[image]

Comment: Cannot take this as an answer because it is just a different transition animation. The problem remains the same. It leads to the same warning!